# Create sql schema from django models or migrations

Tags: sql, django, django-models, database-schema, django-migrations

I created different models with django 1.8.
Now, to enable other people to have a quickly comprehension, I would create a sql schema from the models or from the migration files (even only from the initial migration file).
Someone knows how does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show the database structure to others, I would rather recommend using the `graph_models` command from *django_extensions*:
http://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html

For example typing

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -g models.png
```

creates a graph with the individual models as nodes and their relations as arcs (assuming you have graphviz installed). You can also create a `dot`-file and render it however you like

Comment: I did what you said and it works for me. Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can squash all migrations for a moment, or delete them for a sec and generate new initial one and then run this command:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate

Comment: I don't want change the migrations file. I would do it on the actual status

Comment: Are you familiar with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` SQL statement?

Comment: Or you can just dump the database in SQL mode.

Comment: Yes. I know sql statements. I need of schema only because I want to see the different characteristics of models and their connections. I don't want the schema to create the database.